# How can I convert this date format to mysql using script

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

I have dates in this type of format: `Jan 6 2015 19:28:24 GMT` and would like to convert to a mysql like format. Is there a way I can do this in mysql because I have the data already in my table by as a string instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`str_to_date`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select str_to_date('Jan 6 2015 19:28:24 GMT', '%M %d %Y %H:%i:%s');
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| str_to_date('Jan 6 2015 19:28:24 GMT', '%M %d %Y %H:%i:%s') |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2015-01-06 19:28:24                                         |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: would I be able to output this to a datetime column in the table? or would I have to do this for each record?

Comment: Sure, just use the column name as `str_to_date(columnA, format)`

Comment: the result of this, how can i put it into a new column?

Comment: Is there a way to use 2 columns? One with the date and one with the time.